# How to Download an mp3 into hidden folder

Tags: java, android, encryption, hidden, hidden-files

I am trying to download an mp3 file from an API into my mobile, I want it to download in a hidden folder.

I tryied the folder name start with "." (eg  .foldername). But this file that I can access fom file manager, It only hidding form gallery and other apps.

Next I tried to **Encrypt** the dowloaded file. The problem that I face is, if the download is stop in the midway due some network issue, at that time what all packets (**mp3**) is downloaed that can acces in file manger,its not encrypting.

That is if downloading is stop when it is 50% , then the 50% of that file is access form the file manager, its only encrypting when the downloading is completing.

Also during file downloaing I can access the file from **File Manager**.

Is there any solution to hide the **downloading** file from the **File Manager**

Comment: I think u should do like that if download is not completed then delete half downloaded file immediately

Comment: That i handeling right now, the issue come during the downloading I can access the file @Nirav Ranpara

Comment: Use some other extension while downloading change to mp3 after completion

Comment: its possible, but if any user get that file user can change the file extension to mp3. it cause security issue @Nirav Ranpara

Comment: thats all I know! I dont have much idea

Comment: ok..@Nirav Ranpara

Comment: Save the file in your applications private directory?